# A Thread blocking onTouch method to return true

Tags: android, multithreading, ontouchlistener, instrumentation, ontouch

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Thread thread = new Thread(){
               @Override
               public void run(){
                       Instrumentation m_Instrumentation = new Instrumentation();

                       m_Instrumentation.sendPointerSync(MotionEvent.obtain(
                               SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                               SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                               MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,tiklanacakX, tiklanacakY, 0));
                       m_Instrumentation.sendPointerSync(MotionEvent.obtain(
                               SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                               SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                               MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,tiklanacakX,tiklanacakY, 0));
               }
           };
           thread.start();

        return true;
    }
```

This is my code's not-working part. Actually it is working, but I always want to listen to the touch activity, with this code you should always touch the screen, it doesn't understand moving finger.

I suppose because of the thread within it, it can't reach the return part somehow.

How can I fix it? Btw as far as i know, the instrumentation should be written in a thread.

Thank you.

Comment: U do **thread.join**...As soon as the call back happens, the main(UI) thread will start the thread and returns true, without waiting for the thread to finish its calculations.

Comment: I tried this, now it doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: Why do u want this functionality in another thread and what does the main thread do until the thread is executing run..By what means does the Threads run method effect the functionality of the main activity.